# PixiJS only draws a certain amount of rectangles?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I want to draw a grid dynamically (based on the user defined size) with Pixi.js.
My code is pretty straightforward:

```
let app, graphics;

const cellSize = 10;

initBoard();
updateGridAlgorithm(false, true, 53);   //does work for values < 53

function initBoard() {
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    const height = window.innerHeight;

    app = new PIXI.Application({
        width: width,
        height: 900,
        backgroundColor: 0xffffff,
        resolution: window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
        autoResize: true,
        antialias: true
    });

    document.body.appendChild(app.view);
    graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();

    app.stage.addChild(graphics);
}

function updateGridAlgorithm(randomStart, showGrid, iterations){
    graphics.clear();
    if(showGrid){
        drawNewGrid(iterations);
    }
}

function drawNewGrid(iterations){
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    const gridWidth = iterations * 2 + 1;
    const startX = width/2 - gridWidth/2 * cellSize;
    const startY = 20;

    for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < gridWidth; j++) {
            graphics.lineStyle(0.5, 0x999999);
            graphics.drawRect(startX+j*cellSize, startY+i*cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works for values smaller than **53** (see comment in code). For values higher than that, there seems to be a *constant* limit of how many rectangles can be drawn (~5461). In order to visualize that, test with a larger number.

I also made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g6hwvx5b/) for you to play around (advice: use **Tabs (rows)** editor layout for best results...).

### Detailed explanation of the Problem

For values below **53** (e.g. 52 iterations) I get the correct result, which looks like that:
[image: 52 iterations]
Notice the number of rects is 52*(52*2+1) = 5460 which is smaller than 5461 (difference of 1 seems pure coincidence).

For values greater or equal 53, some rectangles at the end of the grid are not drawn. The missing rectangles are marked red in the following picture:
[image: 53 iterations]
According to my analysis below, there should be 53*(53*2+1)-5461=210 rectangles missing.

There seems to be a **constant maximum of how many rectangles** are drawn at most. I will try to roughly calculate that using 194 iterations:
[image: 194 iterations]
So the number of rectangles drawn is 14 * (194*2+1) + 15 = 5461 which I suspect is the **maximum** number of rectangles that can be drawn.

This same number can be obtained for other iteration counts like for example 209: 13 * (209 * 2 + 1) + 14.

### Concrete Question

I would like to know, why the above described problem occurs and how I can fix it (e.g. draw the full grid for more than 52 iterations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your code works for values greater than 53. For 1000 it doesnt work indeed. To understand why please try running following version of your `drawNewGrid` function:

```
function drawNewGrid(iterations){
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    const gridWidth = iterations * 2 + 1;
    const startX = width/2 - gridWidth/2 * cellSize;
    const startY = 20;

    var countAllRectangles = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < gridWidth; j++) {
            graphics.lineStyle(0.5, 0x991111);
            graphics.drawRect(startX+j*cellSize, startY+i*cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);

            countAllRectangles++;
        }
    }

    console.log(countAllRectangles);
}
```

Run it and observe the Devtools console in browser. When the `iterations` is 500 then it prints: 500500. Also please take a look at "Memory" tab in Chrome Devtools:

- when `iterations` is 100 then `countAllRectangles` is 20100 and i see around 25 MB memory usage.
- when `iterations` is 200 then `countAllRectangles` is 80200 and i see around 90 MB memory usage.
- when `iterations` is 300 then `countAllRectangles` is 180300 and i see around 200 MB memory usage.
- when `iterations` is 400 then `countAllRectangles` is 320400 and i see around 370 MB memory usage.
- when `iterations` is 500 then `countAllRectangles` is 500500 and i see around 570 MB memory usage.
- when `iterations` is 600 then `countAllRectangles` is 720600 and i see around 840 MB memory usage etc.

Memory usage is [increasing quadratically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_growth) along with `iterations` value. It's because of the `for` loop nested inside other `for` loop in function `drawNewGrid`.

This means that for `iterations` of 1000 it will take around 2 GB of memory and will draw around 2 millions rectangles - which is probably too much for our browsers and pixi.js to handle :)

### Update 2020-03-15:

> @frankenapps:
>   Are you sure, the code worked correct for values bigger than 52? I have updated my question with a detailed explanation of my problem...

Ok - now i see more clearly what you had in mind. It seems that there is indeed a limit: number of primitives of one "PIXI.Graphics" object. Please read here:

- https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/12242-a-limitation-on-the-number-of-graphics-primitives/
- https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/5707#issuecomment-494722310

Solution to this problem is to draw more smaller rectangles instead of one PIXI.Graphics object with many rectangles inside. Please check new version of JSFiddle with `iterations = 100`:

- I changed creation of PIXI.Application so it has width and height depending on `iterations` so we will see all rectangles that are drawn:

```
    let canvasWidth = (iterations * 2 + 4) * cellSize;
    let canvasHeight = (iterations + 4) * cellSize;

...

    app = new PIXI.Application({
        width: canvasWidth,
        height: canvasHeight,
```

- also please notice what is happening in `updateGridAlgorithm` function - `gridContainer` is removed from stage and new instance of it is created (if there was something else in `gridContainer` before then it will be garbage collected to free memory).
- and please see `drawNewGrid` function - inside the nested `for` loops new rectangle is being drawn on each step - and then is added to `gridContainer`:

```
      let rectangle = new PIXI.Graphics();
      rectangle.lineStyle(0.5, 0x999999);
      rectangle.beginFill(0xFF << (i % 24)); // draw each row of rectangles in different color :)
      rectangle.drawRect(startX+j*cellSize, startY+i*cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
      rectangle.endFill();

      gridContainer.addChild(rectangle);
```

- i also renamed some variables

https://jsfiddle.net/bmxfoh1r/1/

Comment: Are you sure, the code worked correct for values bigger than 52? I have updated my question with a detailed explanation of my problem...

Comment: You will have to scroll to the bottom of the results pane in order to see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There does seam to be a limit to the number of items that can be added to the graphics object.

### How to solve the problem?

I am not familiar with Pixi.js and the documentation for [`PIXI.Graphics`](https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Graphics.html) provided no easy solution.

Some quick solutions that will (or may) work but will depend on how you intend to use the grid.

1. (Maybe but best option if possible) Create a graphic with only one square (drop the bottom and right edges), convert it to a bitmap and then draw that bitmap over the area you want the grid using repeat (As you would do using [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.createPattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern). How you would do this in Pixi I do not know as a search for "repeat" found nothing of use in the documentation
2. Rather than render rectangles, render lines. This means you only need to add `iterations + gridWidth + 2` lines rather than `(iterations * (gridWidth + 1)` which is a huge saving of resources. (see example code below)
3. (Hacky method) Use as many graphics object as needed to hold the squares. IE if you can only add 5460 rectangles and want to add 15000 you will need to create `Math.ceil(15000 / 5460)` graphics objects. Use a counter to track the number you add to each graphic and switch when each is full.

### Example using poly lines

```
const maxLines = Math.max(iterations, gridWidth);
const right = startX + gridWidth * cellSize;
const bottom = startY + iterations * cellSize;

graphics.startPoly();
var i = 0;
while (i <= maxLines) {
    if (i <= gridWidth) {
       graphicxs.moveTo(startX + i * cellSize, startY);
       graphicxs.lineTo(startX + i * cellSize, bottom);
    }
    if (i <= iterations) {
       graphicxs.moveTo(startX, startY + i * cellSize, startY);
       graphicxs.lineTo(right,  startY + i * cellSize, startY)
    }
    i++;
}
graphics.finishPoly();
```