# PIXI Graphics "Out of Memory"

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, crash, pixi.js

I tried to modify the following code (that draws splash animations on canvas directly):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var particles = [];

canvas.onmousemove = function(e)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 36 * 2; i++)
    {
        particles.push({
            x: e.clientX,
            y: e.clientY,
            angle: i * 5,
            size: 5 + Math.random() * 3,
            life: 200 + Math.random() * 50
        });
    }
}

canvas.onmouseup = function()
{
    //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
}

var delta = 0;
var last = Date.now();

function animate()
{
    delta = Date.now() - last;
    last = Date.now();
    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++)
    {
        var p = particles[i];
        p.x += Math.cos(p.angle) * 4 + Math.random() * 2 - Math.random() * 2;
        p.y += Math.sin(p.angle) * 4 + Math.random() * 2 - Math.random() * 2;
        p.life -= delta;
        p.size -= delta / 50;
        
        if (p.size <= 0)
        {
            p.life = 0;
        }
        
        if (p.life <= 0)
        {
            particles.splice(i--, 1);
            continue;
        }
    }
}

function render()
{
    ctx.fillStyle = '#' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * (0xFFFFFF + 1))).toString(16);
    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++)
    {
        if (Math.random() < 0.1)
        {
            continue;
        }
        var p = particles[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.fill();
    }
}

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

(function animloop(){
    requestAnimFrame(animloop);
    animate();
    render();
})();
```

...to draw using PIXI.Graphics:

```
const app = new PIXI.Application({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    backgroundColor: 0x1099bb,
    resolution: window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
    resizeTo: window
});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

const graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
app.stage.addChild(graphics);

ctx = {
    beginPath: function() {
        graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00);
    },
    arc: function() {
        graphics.arc(...arguments);
    },
    fill: function() {
        graphics.endFill();
    }
};

//var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
//var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var particles = [];

window.onmousemove = function(e)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 36 * 2; i++)
    {
        particles.push({
            x: e.clientX,
            y: e.clientY,
            angle: i * 5,
            size: 5 + Math.random() * 3,
            life: 200 + Math.random() * 50
        });
    }
}

window.onmouseup = function()
{
    //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
}

var delta = 0;
var last = Date.now();

function animate()
{
    delta = Date.now() - last;
    last = Date.now();
    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++)
    {
        var p = particles[i];
        p.x += Math.cos(p.angle) * 4 + Math.random() * 2 - Math.random() * 2;
        p.y += Math.sin(p.angle) * 4 + Math.random() * 2 - Math.random() * 2;
        p.life -= delta;
        p.size -= delta / 50;
        
        if (p.size <= 0)
        {
            p.life = 0;
        }
        
        if (p.life <= 0)
        {
            particles.splice(i--, 1);
            continue;
        }
    }
}

function render()
{
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++)
    {
        if (Math.random() < 0.1)
        {
            continue;
        }
        var p = particles[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.fill();
    }
}

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

(function animloop(){
    requestAnimFrame(animloop);
    animate();
    render();
})();
```

It seems to work, however after a few splashes it starts lagging and eventually crashes the browser with "Out of Memory" error.

The original code draws on mouse click, but I tried and it works on mouse move too.

My idea is that PIXI.Graphics creates too much cache causing the crash.

Does anybody know the reason of the crash and maybe a way to fix it?
Any ideas are appreciated!

Codepen HTML for testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
        <title>PIXI Splash Test</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                height: 100vh;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/5.3.3/pixi.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possibly that many particles/second is too high, does it work better if you reduce 36 * 2

Comment: I tried that but it crashes the same way. Looks like graphics.geometry.graphicsData stores all the circles, which might cause the issues, however clearing it with graphics.clear() removes everything visible. Is there a way to directly draw to canvas without using PIXI.graphics?

Answer (score 0):

1. Is better to use more small "Graphics" objects - instead of one "Graphics" object with many shapes inside it. Please read second part of this answer" (after "Update 2020-03-15) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60686761/3174731
2. Remove unneded objects / containers from "Pixi stage" when you dont need to use them anymore. When you remove the particles (when you do `particles.splice(i--, 1);`) you should also call `app.stage.removeChild(somePixiContainer)` (`Graphics` object is a PIXI.Container too - see "Extends" in https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Graphics.html )